# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/model/bpmn/instance/FlowNode

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, bpmn, camunda

I am trying to create a web REST service using Java, jersey and camunda lib to build up a bpmn project.

My project takes two files from the user by an HTML form page and should create two aut files from them on a specific destination.

I got this error when I upload the files on the server.

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/model/bpmn/instance/FlowNode

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/model/bpmn/instance/FlowNode
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/model/bpmn/instance/FlowNode
    com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.JerseyFileUpload.uploadFile(JerseyFileUpload.java:66)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.camunda.bpm.model.bpmn.instance.FlowNode
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1269)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
    com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.JerseyFileUpload.uploadFile(JerseyFileUpload.java:66)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

The process creates the .aut files with 0 bytes.

Why did I get this error? I add the lib that contains the flownode class in my project. Why won't it work?

edit: I run it with Eclipse ide using Tomcat as server. I already add all the lib in my WEB-INF folder in my java build path libraries.

Comment: Are you using maven? How are you packaging your code? Is it a jar, war or ear? If it is a war, are the libs present in the WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: Yes i use maven project, eclipse and tomcat. And yes the lib arein the web-inf folder!

Comment: are you running inside eclipse or deploying the war separately in tomcat?
Have you tried deleting the exploded war and starting the server again?

Comment: No i run it inside eclipse! and i try the "clean Tomcat work directory" option on the server tab but i still got the error.

Comment: remove the deployed war, delete the server, add the server, add the project again and try it. 
You can try deploying the war separately in tomcat as well.

Comment: Done all this thing. Even if i run directly the war file with Tomcat i got the same error!

Comment: Your war is not getting packaged correctly IMHO. Try putting the jar file in the `<tomcat>\lib` folder.

Comment: I try this and now after i launch the form.html i got a blank page! dont know why!

Comment: check the error in the tomcat logs.

Comment: Same error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/model/bpmn/instance/FlowNode

Comment: most likely you are using an incorrect jar. Check if the class FlowNode is present in your jar and that it is present in only one jar.

Comment: Still nothing. And i update all my jars!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: this exception tells you that at **runtime** the JVM running your code does **not** find that class.

It doesn't matter that your *build* or IDE project setup includes that dependency.

You have to make sure that the **classpath** setup for the JVM that runs your Jersey server contains the library as well.